# Insert values into a table with a foreign key using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I want to insert values in a table containing foreign keys, but when I add the foreign keys manually (for example, addin the id of the foreign key manually by writing it's number), it doesn't work and it   me the error of a wrong syntax.

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FOREIGN KEY,
>
> id_livreur int FOREIGN KEY,
>
> id_plat int FOREIGN KEY,
>
> id_dessert ' at line 4

Here is my table that contains foreign keys :

```
CREATE TABLE Commande
(
id_commande int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
id_client int FOREIGN KEY,
id_livreur int FOREIGN KEY,
id_plat int FOREIGN KEY,
id_dessert int FOREIGN KEY  ,
prix_total int,
heure_estime time,
FOREIGN KEY (id_client) REFERENCES Client(id_client),
FOREIGN KEY (id_livreur) REFERENCES Livreur(id_livreur),
FOREIGN KEY (id_plat) REFERENCES Plat(id_plat),
FOREIGN KEY (id_dessert) REFERENCES Dessert(id_dessert)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And here are my inserts :

```
INSERT INTO Commande VALUES (1,1,1,1,1,45,now() + INTERVAL 20 minute);
INSERT INTO Commande VALUES (2,2,2,2,2,55,now() + INTERVAL 20 minute);
INSERT INTO Commande VALUES (3,3,3,3,3,75,now() + INTERVAL 20 minute);
INSERT INTO Commande VALUES (4,4,4,4,4,45,now() + INTERVAL 20 minute);
```

Comment: Why the sql-server tag?

Comment: remove "FOREIGN KEY" after the column definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove "FOREIGN KEY" after the column definition

```
CREATE TABLE Commande
(
id_commande int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
id_client int,
id_livreur int,
id_plat int ,
id_dessert int,
prix_total int,
heure_estime time,
FOREIGN KEY (id_client) REFERENCES Client(id_client),
FOREIGN KEY (id_livreur) REFERENCES Livreur(id_livreur),
FOREIGN KEY (id_plat) REFERENCES Plat(id_plat),
FOREIGN KEY (id_dessert) REFERENCES Dessert(id_dessert)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: That fixed it... Thanks! Sorry, beginner here x)